# how to adjust raw data font into semibold in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how to turn raw data font into semibold in c++?.

since I don't master the language of the c++ program maybe there is the best solution?
or is there another way ?

Thanks

```
bbool device_PRT::Write(Bit8u * data, Bit16u * size)
{
    Bit8u * datasrc = data;
    Bit8u * datadst = data;

    int numSpaces = 0;
    for (Bit16u idx = *size; idx; idx--)
    {
        if (*datasrc == 0x0c)
            ffWasLast = true;
        else if (!isspace(*datasrc))
            ffWasLast = false;
        if (*datasrc == ' ')                                                        // Put spaces on hold
            numSpaces++;
        else
        {
            if (numSpaces && *datasrc != 0x0a && *datasrc != 0x0d)                  // Spaces on hold and not end of line
            {
                while (numSpaces--)
                    *(datadst++) = ' ';
                numSpaces = 0;
            }
            //          if (*datasrc)
            *(datadst++) = *datasrc;
        }
        datasrc++;
    }
    while (numSpaces--)
        *(datadst++) = ' ';
    if (Bit16u newsize = datadst - data)                                            // If data
    {
        if (rawdata.capacity() < 100000)                                            // Prevent repetive size allocations
            rawdata.reserve(100000);
        rawdata.append((char *)data, newsize);
#pragma warning(suppress: 28159)
        timeOutAt = GetTickCount() + LPT_LONGTIMEOUT;                                   // Long timeout so data is printed w/o Close()
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is 'raw data font'?

Comment: @PaulSanders , the code is from the source code of the vdos program. raw data generated from the dos program